# Como mudar o @GeneratedValue usado pelo Spring atraves da classe AbstractPersistable do Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Eu gostaria de usar o `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, ... ...` quando estiver estendendo a classe `AbstractPersistable`, porem não sei se isso é possível.

Pelo que eu vi na documentação a classe  `AbstractPersistable` possui o atributo `Id` com a anotação `@GeneratedValue` mas não informa qual a estratégia usada pela anotação `@GeneratedValue` para  criar a sequência usada pelo framework Spring.

Como faço para usar o  `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` especificamente  estendendo a classe  `AbstractPersistable` para ter uma maior produtividade?

Comment: Só utilizar `SequenceGenerator` na entidade que herda de `AbstractPersistable`, não? Daí teria que fazer em todas que herdarem de `AbstractPersistable`. Para abstrair isto, crie uma `AbstractPersistable` própria.

Comment: É verdade, alguns desenvolvedores usam essa pratica. Podeira demonstrar como criar uma AbstractPersistable  propria @BrunoCesar;